# SQL ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer algumas alterações no meu banco, porém antes de adicionar uma nova coluna preciso verificar se ela já existe, se não existir criar a nova coluna se não existir a coluna então devera criar

Comando encontrado para verificar existência da coluna

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS resultado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'procedimentos_planos_tratamentos' AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'tipo';
```

se o retorno for 1 não fazer nada e se o retorno for 0 executar seguinte procedimento

```
ALTER TABLE procedimentos_planos_tratamentos
ADD COLUMN tipo VARCHAR(1);
```

Comment: Aqui tem algumas formas de fazer isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira

```
    IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS resultado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'procedimentos_planos_tratamentos' AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'tipo') THEN
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE procedimentos_planos_tratamentos
        ADD COLUMN tipo VARCHAR(1);  
  END;
  END IF;
```